# Usestate not working in sync with checkbox

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a multi checkbox and using a usestate function to push the checked values to an array. But when i check one checkbox its value gets pushed to the array only when i am checking other option.

For ex:

1. If i check red option, nothing is pushed to array.
2. If i check blue option, only red value(which was previously checked) is pushed to array.
3. If i check green option, red and blue values are only present in array

Below is my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { filterProducts } from "../../redux/Shopping/shopping-actions";

const filterValues = [
  {
    heading: "Colour",
    items: ["Red", "Blue", "Green"],
  },
  {
    heading: "Gender",
    items: ["Men", "Women"],
  },
  {
    heading: "Price",
    items: ["0-Rs250", "Rs251-450", "Rs 450"],
  },
  {
    heading: "Type",
    items: ["Polo", "Hoodie", "Classic"],
  },
];

const Filter = ({ filter, searchArray, setSearchArray }) => {
  
  const handleCheck = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked === true) {
      setSearchArray([...searchArray, e.target.value]);
    } else {
      setSearchArray(searchArray.filter((id) => id !== e.target.value));
    }
    if (searchArray.length > 0) {
      filter(searchArray);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <aside className="ml-4 mt-16">
        {filterValues.map((item) => {
          return (
            <>
              <h3 className="mb-4 mt-2 ml-4 font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-black">
                {item.heading}
              </h3>

              <ul className="w-48 text-sm font-medium text-black-900 bg-white dark:text-white">
                {item.items.map((i) => {
                  return (
                    <li className="w-full rounded-t-lg">
                      <div className="flex items-center pl-3">
                        <input
                          id="checkbox"
                          type="checkbox"
                          value={i}
                          onChange={(e) => handleCheck(e)}
                          className="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 rounded border-gray-300 focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:ring-blue-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-700 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-600 dark:border-gray-500"
                        />
                        <label
                          for="checkbox"
                          className="py-3 ml-2 w-full text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-black"
                        >
                          {i}
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  );
                })}
              </ul>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </aside>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    filter: (query) => dispatch(filterProducts(query)),
  };
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Filter);
```

Filter function

```
case actionTypes.FILTER_PRODUCT:
      const searchParameters = data && Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...data));
      let filterData;
      console.log("testing", action.payload);

      if (action.payload.length === 0) {
        filterData = state.products;
      } else {
        action.payload.forEach((i) => {
          filterData = state.products.filter((item) =>
            searchParameters.some((parameter) =>
              item[parameter]
                .toString()
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(i.toLowerCase())
            )
          );
        });
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        filteredData: filterData,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
```

Comment: Can you please also share your `filter` and `setSearchArray` functions that you pass into the `Filter` component as props? The behaviour could depend greatly on what they do and how they do it.

Comment: Hi @benomatis, setSearchArray is just a usestate function but sharing the filter function which is a redux action ```

Comment: is `setSearchArray` also used in the parent component? if not, is there a reason you define it in the parent and not in the `Filter` component?

Comment: yeah it is used in parent component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call **setSearchArray** to update the state, the updated value is not immediately available in the next line of code.
So when you check the first checkbox, the updated state is not available yet and the length of **searchArray** is still zero. Thats why the first checkbox value is not being added to the array.

To fix this issue, you can pass a function to **setSearchArray** instead of the new value. This function will receive the previous state as an argument and should return the new state based on the previous state. This is how you can ensure that you are always updating the state based on the latest value.

```js
const Filter = ({ filter }) => {
  const [searchArray, setSearchArray] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchArray.length > 0) {
      filter(searchArray);
    }
  }, [searchArray]);

  const handleCheck = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked === true) {
      setSearchArray([...searchArray, e.target.value]);
    } else {
      setSearchArray(searchArray.filter((id) => id !== e.target.value));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {filterValues.map((item) => {
        return (
          <div key={item.heading}>
            <h3>{item.heading}</h3>
            <ul>
              {item.items.map((i) => {
                return (
                  <li key={i}>
                    <label>
                      <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        value={i}
                        checked={searchArray.includes(i)}
                        onChange={(e) => handleCheck(e)}
                      />
                      {i}
                    </label>
                  </li>
                );
              })}
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

*useEffect* hook is used to call the filter function whenever the searchArray state is updated. The **searchArray** state is updated using the **setSearchArray** function as before. The **handleCheck** function is also updated to use the **searchArray** state directly, and to check whether the value is already in the array before adding or removing it.

Comment: I used the code, but still the same issue it is not working in sync

Comment: Try the updated code, you can use the useEffect hook to call the filter function whenever the searchArray state is updated. The filter function is called with the latest values in the searchArray state.

Comment: Yeah with useeffect it worked, thanks